# Calculating Large Number Power

Tags: microsoft-excel, octave

I am actually looking for a solution to be able to calculate this Excel formula:

```
=1-PERMUT(1.15*10^77,358*10^7)/(1.15*10^77)^(358*10^7)
```

I tried to solve it in Octave too.

Is there any solution for such large number calculations anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a direct calculation you must use shortcuts and simplification
as the direct calculation does not fit in the numerical representation
of the math of the system:

```
octave:1> (1.15*10^77)^(358*10^7)
ans =  Inf
```

Using approximation for small x
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

```
log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)
exp(x) = 1 + x + O(x^2)
```

as the ratio of your number justifis it:

```
octave:1> n=1.15*10^77
n =    1.1500e+77
octave:2> k=358*10^7
k =  3580000000
octave:3> k/n
ans =    3.1130e-68
```

We can start modifying the 2nd portion of your calculation using

```
P(n,k) = n! / (n-k)!
```

so the ratio

```
PERMUT(1.15*10^77,358*10^7)/(1.15*10^77)^(358*10^7)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
P(n,k) / n^k = 

= n! / (n-k)! / n^k
= (n/n) *(n-1)/n * (n-2) /n * .... *(n-k+1)/n=
= 1 * (1-1/n) * (1-2/n) * ... * (1-(k-1)/n)
```

passing to its logarithmic

```
log( P(n,k) / n^k ) = 
= log (1 * (1-1/n) * (1-2/n) * ... * (1-(k-1)/n) ) =
= log(1) + log(1-1/n)+ log(1-2/n) + ... + log(1-(k-1)/n) =
=~ 0 + (-1/n) + (-2/n) + ... + (-(k-1)/n) = 
= - ( 1+2+..+(k-1) )/n = - k*(k-1)/(2*n)
```

and then back

```
P(n,k) / n^k = exp(log( P(n,k) / n^k ) ) =~ exp(- k*(k-1)/(2*n))
=~ 1 - k*(k-1)/(2*n)
```

so finally

```
1-PERMUT(1.15*10^77,358*10^7)/(1.15*10^77)^(358*10^7)=
= 1 - (1 - k*(k-1)/(2*n) ) = 
= k*(k-1)/(2*n) 

octave:4> k*(k-1)/(2*n)
ans =    5.5723e-59
```